# overflow property not working in Amazon Kindle Fire WebView

Tags: javascript, android, css, html, webview

I have developed an Android application and most of the application GUI is developed using HTML5.I am using WebView to render HTML5 contents. It seems to be working on all major Android versions but I am having serious problem on Amazon Kindle Fire. The **overflow** property is not working properly and due to this reason there are scrolling issues. I checked whether overflow property is supported or not using

```
 if('overflow' in document.body.style)
```

and the result was true. But when I apply this property to **ul** there is no affect. Kindly help to fix this problem. I don't want to re-write application for Kindle Fire using Android SDK. Here is the sample code which isn't working:

```
   <STYLE type="text/css">
        #list-container{
            left:0px;
            width:1024px;
            height:200px;
            padding:0px;
            margin:0px;
        }

        #image-list{
            height:200px;
            width:1024px;
            margin:0px;
            padding:0px;

            display:block;
            white-space:nowrap;

            overflow:scroll;
        }

        #image-list li{
            background-color:black;
            list-style:none;
            height:170px;
            width:194px;
            display:inline-block;    
        }

<body style='width:1024px;height:600px;background-color:white;overflow-x:scroll;'>

    <div id='list-container'>
        <ul id='image-list'>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </div> 

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Kindle Fire is based in on an older version of Android. Thus `overflow: scroll` is not supported.

However, [iScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll)is a popular script that offers a lot of scrolling related features.

Comment: Is it possible to implement scrolling using mousedown, mousemove events. Any sample code or reference would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I've updated my answer to add an iscroll reference. You might want to look into that.

Comment: Thanks. I am going to give it a try.

Comment: It seems very promising. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Kindle Fire, first generation, were based on Android 2.3.3, API level 10. All the rest are based on Android 4.0.3, API level 15. Ref: https://developer.amazon.com/sdk/fire/specifications.html